# CoreData gets emptied after adding data into it

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a CoreData entity `Tracker` which stores the dates. 
The app receives a notification and the `CheckListViewController` enters data in CoreData for up to 13 days, so when the CheckListViewController gets dismissed, the CoreData entity `Tracker` will be filled with 13 rows.

In the `MainViewController` (which dismisses `CheckListViewController`), I have the following code:

```
    - (void)dataSaved {
        self.checkListVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
              // fetching all the data from 'Tracker' entity and doing NSLog on it
              // all data gets logged in console without any issues
        }];
    }
```

Now, after that somewhere in my code, I fetch all the data from the entity `Tracker` but the return data is empty. The CoreData doesn't show any error it simply returns and empty array.

Edit: 
Code to fetch results from CoreData

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:ENTITY];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
[request setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
request.predicate = (fromDate && toDate) ? [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date >= %@ AND date <= %@", fromDate, toDate] : nil;

__block NSArray* fetchedHabits;
[managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
    NSError *error = nil;
    fetchedHabits = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    if (error) NSLog(@"Unknown error occurred while fetching results from CoreData, %@ : %@", error, [error userInfo]);
}];
```

CoreData model:
[image]

**Update 1**:
So as you can see there are two entities, namely `Habit` and `Tracker`. When I fetch results from `Habit` it all works fine, but when I try to fetch results from `Tracker` it gives me an empty array. I have a common `NSManagedObjectContext` instance because you can manage multiple CoreData entities with single `managedObjectContext`.
I have checked `managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator.managedObjectModel.entitiesByName` and it also lists both the entities.

**Update 2**:
Code where I add data in to `Tracker`

```
TrackerCoreData *tracker = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:ENTITY
                                                                     inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
tracker.date = date;
tracker.habits = habits;

// saving CoreData explicitly
NSError *error = nil;
[managedObjectContext save:&error];
```

Comment: can you show code how you are saving objects in coredata.

Comment: It would be nice to see the code you use to save the objects.

Comment: try removing your `performBlockAndWait` and just execute it on the main thread. Also why is your `save` not working? Do you get an exception?

Comment: @Firo..with/without performBlockAndWait, not working. When I said `save` is not working I meant that even after that it is not working. `save` doesn't produce any errors.

Answer (score 0):

There could be many reasons for your failure to display the records:

- data was not saved
- data was not retrieved correctly
- data was not displayed correctly

All of these could be potentially complicated scenarios, but you should check them in this order.

A much better approach: use `NSFetchedResultsController` for your main view controller and have the delegate methods take care of updating your table view. No need to fetch, no work to be done in any completion methods - just save the data and the FRC will update your table.

**Edit: how to check the physical database**
It is possible that your data only exists in memory but is not actually saved to the database. Find the actual database file (in the documents folder of the app from the Simulator) and check it with the `sqlite3` command line utility, or with the Firefox plugin "SQLite Manager".

**Edit2: more concrete recommendations**
You should make sure that you call:

```
[managedObjectContext save:&error];
```

Also double-check what your `ENTITY` macro stands for (not a very smart name).

It seems to me that you are overusing the block methods to no apparent purpose. First try to make everything work on the main thread (one context!). Only if you get performance problems consider background threads and context and calls to `performBlock` etc.

Comment: 1. Data was saved, as I have already told that I am fetching the data in `dissmissViewControllerAnimated` and it is displaying. But later that when I fetch the data, it returns the empty data.
2. When I am retrieving the data, I am setting predicate to `nil` so that all the data can be fetched. But that comes to be empty.
3. There is no point of 'not displaying correctly' because I am checking data via `NSLog`, not via any tableView

Also, I need the data to draw a graph thats why I can't use NSFetchResultsController.

Comment: Best way to check if your data is really existing in coredata is to check the DB itself. It might be that the data you have are only "TempData"

Comment: How to go about check the Database itself?

Comment: Can you please check whether you are using same instance of `NSManagedObjectContext` for save and fetch. It happens sometimes that different `NSManagedObjectContext`s are used for different operations. FYI: `NSManagedObjectContext` doesn't save to DB/NSManagedDocument immediately, it keeps data in memory and save after few seconds. So if different `context` is used to fetch data saved  by other `context` then it might come as blank.

Comment: There is a singleton class that manages `NSManagedObjectContext`. It checks if the `context` is not present, then only it creates it. I have updated my question with CoreData model.

Comment: I gave you some more advice above: did you call `save:`?

Comment: 1. Did you use #define preprocessor for `ENTITY` as you have used that in `fetchRequestWithEntityName:ENTITY`? can you check spelling of entity name string in macro?   
2. can you try using ((date >= %@) AND (date <= %@))?

Comment: @Mundi :`save` is not working either. The reason I am using `performBlock` is to not worry about the thread and stuck into some issue regarding thread mis-match. And I have heard that it is good practice to use `performBlock`, even if everything happens on the main thread.
@SaurabhHooda : The predicate is also working fine. I have checked changing it to alter the fetched results (the only time I am getting data from Tracker CoreData entity) and it worked as expected. Also, the `ENTITY` is correct because when I change its name to some random name, it shows error, otherwise it doesn't.

Comment: I hope you are using `dispatch_once` function while creating your Singleton? If yes, then I guess am out of clues :( All the best!